# chrome.i18n.getMessage is always empty

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to enable i18n to a little chrome extension that I'm working on.

As of now, I only need to translate some strings in the html file. I know that the i18n functionality cannot do that directly, so I wrote my own localization function:

```
var $objects = $('*[data-message]');
$objects.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var messageName = $this.attr('data-message');
    var text = $this.html();
    var translated = chrome.i18n.getMessage(messageName);
    if (translated !== '' && translated !== undefined) {
        $this.html(translated);
    }
    console.log(messageName); // this prints "theTitle"
    console.log(translated);  // this prints ""
});
```

This is a string that I have in my html file:

```
<span data-message="theTitle">Live Quotes Portfolio</span>
```

And this is my `_locales/it/messages.json` file:

```
{
    "theTitle": {
        "message": "Il titolo",
        "description": "The string we search for.."
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the two console logs, the first one prints the correct string that needs to be translated, but the second is always empty.

What am I missing? I also have `"default_locale": "it"` in my `manifest.json`...

Comment: Have you *reloaded* the extension on chrome://extensions page? It's required when editing messages.json file. BTW you can translate via CSS e.g. `#title:before { content: "__MSG_theTitle__" }`

Comment: No indeed, but you were right... reloading the extension solved my problem. I've spent hours trying to fix this, lol :) Thanks!!